# IntelliJ - inputting unescaped UTF-8 non ASCII characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf

I have a program in which I want to put in Strings containing unescaped Unicode characters, e.g.

```
String s = "(¬(a) ∨ ((¬(b) ∧ (c ∨ d)) ∨ e))"
```

The problem is that this string is already gets read wrongly, as the Unicode characters aren't escaped, so if I immediately print it, I get:

```
(Â¬(a) â¨ ((Â¬(b) â§ (c â¨ d)) â¨ e))
```

Of cause, if I escape the Unicode characters in the string, it just works fine:

```
String s = "(\u00AC(a) \u2228 ((\u00AC(b) \u2227 (c \u2228 d)) \u2228 e))"
System.out.println(s); 

Output:
(¬(a) ∨ ((¬(b) ∧ (c ∨ d)) ∨ e))
```

However, compared to the first input, the second can only be described as ominous, and is everything but clear.

Is there a way to keep the visual representation, and still have it work?

File Encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Have you tried saving the source code as UTF-8? https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: @Malt Yes, I've set the encoding to UTF-8. If I e.g. open it in Notepad, it gets shown as the correct Unicode as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically when you read a `String` like that in java you can keep presentation, see example here: https://ideone.com/krMJRf

The same thing works as well in new InteliJ `hello-world` template app.

I guess but you did not mention in the question - that you are reading a file. The file needs to have good encoding to make it work.

Comment: I did exactly what you did in your example, and it didn't work. Turns out that a single file in your project that isn't UTF-8 encoded means no other file (no matter how unrelated) can be read in in UTF-8. Thanks for the working example, otherwise I would have never gotten that it was some particularity that somewhere arised from my project structure!